# How to predict a H2O GBM model for nth tree?

Tags: python, h2o, interaction, multilabel-classification, gbm

pros_gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(nfolds=0,seed=1234, keep_cross_validation_predictions = False, ntrees=1000, max_depth=3, learn_rate=0.01, distribution='multinomial')
pros_gbm.train(x=predictors, y=target, training_frame=hf_train, validation_frame = hf_test)

pros_gbm.predict(hf_test)

Currently, I am predicting my test data like above, but how can I predict my test data for the nth tree(out of 1000 trees) of this model? is there any option in "predict" for that, or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the predicted probabilities (cumulative for each tree) using [`staged_predict_proba()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html#h2o.model.model_base.ModelBase.staged_predict_proba) and the lead node assignments from [`predict_leaf_node_assignment()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html#h2o.model.ModelBase.predict_leaf_node_assignment). Here is an example:

```
from h2o.estimators import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator

# Import the prostate dataset into H2O:
prostate = h2o.import_file("http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/prostate/prostate.csv")

# Set the predictors and response; set the factors:
prostate["CAPSULE"] = prostate["CAPSULE"].asfactor()
predictors = ["ID","AGE","RACE","DPROS","DCAPS","PSA","VOL","GLEASON"]
response = "CAPSULE"

# Build and train the model:
pros_gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(nfolds=5,
                                        seed=1111,
                                        keep_cross_validation_predictions = True)
pros_gbm.train(x=predictors, y=response, training_frame=prostate)

print(pros_gbm.predict_leaf_node_assignment(prostate[:1, :]))
print(pros_gbm.staged_predict_proba(prostate[:1, :]))
```

You can also check out the [Tree Class](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/tree.html) if you want details (leaf/split info) for each tree.